# In using the CSS scale property to shrink a CSS logo, the div seems to to maintain its original size although its content shrinks. Any tips?

Tags: css

Novice here, so thanks in advance for your patience and help.

I'm playing around with creating a logo in CSS (mainly because I don't have Photoshop or knowledge of similar programs), and I'm interested in scaling the image for when I may need various sized versions of it. I tried to zoom property, which distorted the logo somewhat, but the scale property seems to work well. The issue I'm encountering is that although the div *appears* to scale properly, it seems as though the div maintains its specified width/height (167px, 167px) but half of it is now filled with blank space. Is that what's going on or am I missing something? Anyone have some solutions?

Here's what I'm describing: http://codepen.io/miskellaneousness/pen/LNXrzv

Here's the div at its original size:

```
.logo1{
 width:167px;
 height:167px;
 border:1px solid black; 
 border-radius:2px;
 float:left;
 -webkit-user-select: none;   
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 margin-left:10px;
 margin-right:0px;
 }
```

Here's the scaled logo:

```
.logo2{
 width:167px;
 height:167px;
 border:1px solid black; 
 border-radius:2px;
 float:left;
 -webkit-user-select: none;   
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 margin-left:0px;
 transform: scale(.5);
 }
```

Comment: What browser are you doing this on? It scales properly for me, and the div occupies only what it should.

Comment: Chrome. It scales properly for me also, but there's a good bit of white space around the small logo despite that margins are set to 0. It's clearer when I duplicate the small logo: http://codepen.io/miskellaneousness/pen/LNXrzv. Why are the two small logos so far apart? That's why it seems as though the div is maintaining its original parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get what you mean now. You're looking for the `transform-origin:;` CSS property. Check this out: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZWmRro

I added `transform-origin: top left;` to your scaled logo. You can specify values like so:

- Center center, top left, bottom center... you get the gist.
- You can also go with percentages like 20% 40%.

Try it out!

Comment: Thanks very much for the help! That does it.

Comment: Although this actually raises a similar question: is it possible to make an element flush against the transformed element? For example, can box 3 be moved against the transformed logo here? http://codepen.io/miskellaneousness/pen/LNXrzv

Comment: No, when you use transform:scale; you change the pixel ratio, not the actual pixels. You'd need some smart JS for actual resizing. Maybe you can fix it by applying margins individually like so: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KzreGQ